# How do I get contextmenu working for the windows phone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

After some googling I saw that ContextMenuService is hiding out in the toolkit, and that is a seperate download.

So I went over to http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435 and dowloaded it. Expecting too much (and a little magic maybe) I still cant use `<toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>` tag :-(.

What do I need to do (from the scratch, did I even donwload the right file?) to get this baby up and running, really want ContextMenus for my lists! :D

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest downloading the [Silvierlight for Windows Phone Toolkit Source & Samples - Nov 2011.zip](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888#DownloadId=304099) and get the samples windows phone app working.  That will show you some really good sample code .. then I'm sure you'll see what you are missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888) not the one for regular Silverlight.

Also, I'll strongly recommend you use [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/SilverlightToolkitWP) instead of manually downloading it.